# How to change these numbers in android (0x7f0b005e) R.java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I'm trying to change colors in one of android apps and the only symbols related to colors are in R.java like this :

```
    public static final int colorButtonNormal = 0x7f010088;
    public static final int colorControlActivated = 0x7f010086;
    public static final int colorControlHighlight = 0x7f010087;
    public static final int colorControlNormal = 0x7f010085;
    public static final int colorPrimary = 0x7f010082;
```

Can you please show me how to change those numbers

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should not try to make changes to R.java since it is an auto-generated file.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a colors.xml file
`~/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml`
in your code base. Only there you can change/add a new color. You cannot edit in R.java

Comment: Yes there is that file, the issue was that when I change colors and generate apk it don't appear to be changed, and everything else changed